# Create a card with recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

my main activity has imageview and I want to create a new card when I clicked it and I wanna manage them. How can add card to layout when I clicked imageview .Here is my cardview layout xml **card_view.xml**

> ```
> <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:id="@+id/cv"
>     >
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:padding="16dp"
>         >
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="300dp"
>             android:layout_height="150dp"
>             android:text="I'm here"
>             android:id="@+id/textView"
>             />
>     </RelativeLayout>
>
> </android.support.v7.widget.CardView> </LinearLayout>
> ```

card class holding just a string

```
public class Card {
String information;
public void setInformation(String info)
{
    information=info;
}
public String getInformation()
{
    return information;
}
```

and here is my adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Card> cards;

public MyAdapter (Context context,List<Card> cards)
{
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.cards=cards;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textview.setText(cards.get(position).information);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cards.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView textview;
    CardView cardView;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textview=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        cardView=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
    }
}
```

and main

```
private MyAdapter adapter;
private List<Card> cards=new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView rv;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    final LinearLayoutManager llm=new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    final Card current=new Card();
    adapter=new MyAdapter(this,cards);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);


    iView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    iView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            current.information="Hello";
            cards.add(current);

            //mLayout.addView();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are changing the underling dataset of the adapter which you use in `ListView` or `RecyclerView` you have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` of the adapter for the changes to take effect.

So in your code where you add a card to your array of cards in `onClick()` method, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.
So change this:

```java
public void onClick(View v) {
            current.information="Hello";
            cards.add(current);

            //mLayout.addView();
                }
            }
```

to this:

```java
public void onClick(View v) {
            current.information="Hello";
            cards.add(current);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //mLayout.addView();
                }
            }
```